# Override the item animator on ViewPager2's recycler view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

Hi I am looking for any advice

I have a ViewPager2 where each page contains a list of items.

The problem is when an update arrives for one of the pages, it seems the recycler view uses a different ViewHolder to display the update, this means I cannot perform smooth animation inside of the list to show the updated item because it is being redrawn.

From my research it seems setting this on the ViewPager2's recycler view would solve the problem but I cannot find any way to set it.

Any advice on alternative ways to fix the problem would be much appreciated.

```
val itemAnimator: DefaultItemAnimator = object : DefaultItemAnimator() {
      override fun canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
            return true
      }
}
recyclerView.itemAnimator = itemAnimator
``
```